# CSS gradients suddenly not working in IE9 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, gradient

For some reason certain gradients are ceasing to work on IE9 (and that is it as far as I know).  On our website there should be a background gradient looking like the sky, and on our main menu navigation mega drop down it should have a blue gradient so that it is joined with the hover from the main nav.

site in question is: http://www.streetstyles4all.co.uk

Can any one advise?

The strange thing is that some gradients are actually working fine. I used a gradient generator to create some of the gradients but I am new to this and am in quite deep and it is beginning to get confusing.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Rob

Comment: You might want to be more specific as to what gradients appear to not be working correctly. For example, with IE set to IE8 or IE7 in Developer Tools, all the gradients appear to work as in Firefox, except for the gradient backgrounds that should appear on mouseover of the menus.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: #00b9ed; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b9ed 0%, #f9fdff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b9ed), color-stop(100%,#f9fdff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b9ed 0%,#f9fdff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b9ed 0%,#f9fdff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b9ed 0%,#f9fdff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b9ed 0%,#f9fdff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b9ed', endColorstr='#f9fdff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

This code will work best in all the Browsers , here is a cross browser compatibility , if you face problem in this , do let me know i will see it myself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, this is working just fine. Check to make sure that you don't have IE9 set to some other browser type in the Developer Tools. Make sure Browser Mode is set to IE9 and Document Mode is set to IE9 standards.

Incidentally, the reason your gradient backgrounds are not showing up on mouseover of the menu items is because you're using a :hover on an li. IE7 and IE8 do not support :hover on any element other than `<a>` tags. Changing your CSS styles just slightly would possibly correct this for you...

```
#general a:hover {
    // your hover effect
}
```

... would be supported in all versions of IE. Of course, you'd have to make sure your `<a>` tag's adjusted to show the non-hover image, first, and that you've set the `<a>` tag to be display:block so it could show everything, but that's minor compared to trying to get IE < 9 to support :hover on non-anchor-tag elements.